How can I improve my Milky Way photography?
For the first time, I took Milky Way pictures last night with a Canon 18-55mm lens, ISO 6400, f/4, 30 sec. I took 10 light and 10 dark pictures, then stacked them in DeepSkyStacker. It turned out as shown below.

In the second picture, I edited in Photoshop as I am doing this very first time watching online help.

Should I edit more in Photoshop, or in different software? Or is it good enough as it is with many stars?

If you like the result, that's all that counts.

Read the whole series of articles about night photography from Clark https://clarkvision.com/articles/astrophotography-made-simple/

Nice first try!
Generally when engaging in astro-photography, there are 4 main things to take into consideration:

Shutter speed - This indicates the speed at which the shutter of the camera closes. The slower it is, the more light it captures, which is ideal in this case. A good rule to go by is the so-called "Rule of 500", in which you can see how long to expose before star trails start to appear. You basically take the number 500 and divide by the focal length of your lens. So for example, if you set your lens at 18-mm, then 500 / 18 ≃ 27 seconds.
Aperture - Set the aperture to the lowest possible f-stop value. Since our goal is to capture light at night, the camera lens should be as wide-open as possible.
ISO - ISO should ideally (for me personally) be between 800-1600. The more you increase ISO, the more likely you'll see noise (In the second image you provided it is actually visible, from the purple/pink dots all around the sky.)
Focus - Keep it manual. When setting it to manual, point to a singular star and try to adjust the lens till that star appears as  small and sharp as possible.

As far as editing goes, less is more.
Basic stuff to experiment with and toggle:

Exposure (Increase)
Contrast (Increase)
Shadows (Increase)
Whites (Increase)
Highlights (Decrease)
Blacks (Decrease)

At the end of the day though, editing is up to you and also depends on the raw file itself.
Good luck!

Does the "rule of 500" assume a full frame camera?  If yes, I guess you'll need to multiply the focal length with the crop factor when using a smaller sensor.

@luator exactly! So for 18-mm lens, the division should in fact be 500/24 (I think that's approximately the analogy)
